# qmake error : could not find a Qt installation of ''

Tags: qt

Error-

$ qmake
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

---

I installed Qt Version 4.8.2

---

Partial File  of .profile in my home directory

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
fi
```

---

Output-

$ which qmake

/usr/bin/qmake

```
Properties
Name        - qmake
Type        - Link to executable (application/x-executable)
Link Target - qtchooser
Location    - /usr/bin
```

---

qmake is present in this location

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin
```

Properties

```
Name        - qmake
Type        - executable (application/x-executable)
Size        - 3.4 MB (3,407,312 bytes)
Location    - /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin
```

---

qmake is also present in this location

```
 /home/username/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/bin
```

Properties

```
Name        - qmake
Type        - executable (application/x-executable)
Size        - 11.2 MB (11,157,974 bytes)
Location    - /home/username/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/bin
```

---

How to make qmake work? Which one is the correct path for qmake?

Comment: `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin` looks like much appropriate location for installed Qt. `/home/username/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/bin` looks like Qt build directory. Try to use only the first path in your PATH.

Comment: run this command in your terminal `$ qmake -v` and see which one is in your default path. if you can't run it from command line you should set your environment variables.

Comment: @MoKi  $ qmake -v 
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

Comment: try `$ env | grep PATH` and see if your `PATH` is set correctly.

Comment: PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin:$PATH
    export PATH
     I tried to change the .profile as per your suggestion but the problem still persists

Comment: you need to specify which one of them should run if you have multiple versions installed in your system.

Comment: @user3520466 You chose where you installed Qt, so why do you ask us where is the `qmake` that came with that Qt? You already know it. It's the only executable named `qmake` in the directory tree where you installed Qt.

Comment: Car analogy: "You just bought a red Ferrari and went to buy a diamond ring for your wedding anniversary. After leaving the jeweler, you find yourself in the parking lot and see a blue, a green and a red Ferrari. You wonder which one is yours...".

Answer (score 0):

I think the source code is in this location:
`/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/bin`
and installation directory is at:
`/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin`

you need to add the installation directory to your PATH, however if you have an other version (like the one in `/usr/bin`) you need to use `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin/qmake` to compile Qt project using this version.

My solution is to add this code to your .profile file:

```
export QTDIR="/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2"
export PATH="$QTDIR/bin:$PATH"
alias qmake-4.8="$QTDIR/bin/qmake"
```

after that use `qmake-4.8` instead of `qmake`

Comment: also if one is using Qt Creator they can do this by selecting Projects icon in the left pane and click on manage kits button to set the `qmake` they are interested in. The rest is really straight forward from there.

Comment: -1 for not understanding the shell expansions. The `QTDIR` is completely superfluous. It's only used to set up the alias. Subsequent modifications of `QTDIR` will have no effect. You would get the same effect if you did the following: `QTDIR="..."; alias qmake-4.8="$QTDIR/bin/qmake"; unset QTDIR`

Comment: @KubaOber QTDIR is an environment variable used by a lot of Qt tools, and i edited my response to add Qt directory to PATH

Comment: @boussouira No, it isn't. AFAICT, it's used by *one* Qt tool: fixqt4headers. That tool is not used for regular builds, just for porting. All other tools built with Qt have the relevant paths hard-coded. That's what makes Qt easy to use, and makes it trivial for multiple versions to coexist. QTDIR used to be relevant in Qt 3 and prior. Not anymore, thankfully. Heck, even `configure` explicitly unsets any QTDIR that may be present. That's also why you can't move a Qt installation without breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple. You don't need to modify any environmental variables, you don't need to set up `QTDIR`. There are only two facts you need to keep in mind:

1. **You must invoke `qmake` from your desired version of Qt.**
2. **There's a 1:1 relationship between a particular installed Qt version and build, and `qmake` executable.**

After the desired `qmake` was run and generated the makefile, invoking `make` will build your project using the version of Qt the `qmake` came from. This will happen *in spite of* any environmental variable settings etc.

So, all you need to know is *which* Qt installation you want to use, and its path. This should be obvious since you installed Qt yourself. There lies the `bin/qmake` that you need.

You can select the desired `qmake` just as you would select a particular binary to run. The process is not any different just because it is `qmake` and not, say `gzip`:

- by explicitly typing out the path to the executable,
- by using a shell alias,
- by putting the desired Qt's `bin` folder onto the PATH.

Only you know where you installed your desired version of Qt - there are at least three paths in your question. Thus it's impossible to tell *which* `qmake` are you to invoke. Obviously one of them - the one picked up by `which qmake` - doesn't work.

You need to invoke the one that came with the version of `Qt` that you installed.

**That's really all there's to it.**